# If $T$ is an isomorphism and $<u,v>$ an inner product, then $<T(u), T(v)>$ is also a inner product.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I have to prove that if $T$ is na isomorphism, then $<T(u), T(v)>$ is also an inner product, when $<u,v>$ is an inner product.

I've tried to assume that, since $<u,v>$ is an inner product, then we have:

$$<u+w,v> = <u, v> + <w, v>$$
$$<au, v> = a<u,v>$$
$$<u,u> > 0$$
$$<u,v> = <v,u>$$

But I couldn't connect any of these assumptions with $T(u)$ and $T(v)$. Also, considering $T(u) = Au$ where $A$ is a matrix didn't help too. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's write $\langle u,v\rangle_T=\langle T(u),T(v)\rangle$. You want to prove that

1. $\langle u+w,v\rangle_T=\langle u,v\rangle_T+\langle w,v\rangle_T$,
2. $\langle au,v\rangle_T=a\langle u,v\rangle_T$,
3. $\langle u,v\rangle_T=\langle v,u\rangle_T$,
4. $\langle u,u\rangle_T>0$ if $u\ne0$.

Let's tackle the first one.

\begin{align}
\langle u+w,v\rangle_T
&=\langle T(u+w),T(v)\rangle &&\text{by definition}\\
&=\langle T(u)+T(w),T(v)\rangle &&\text{by linearity of $T$}\\
&=\langle T(u),T(v)\rangle+\langle T(w),T(v)\rangle &&\text{inner product property}\\
&=\langle u,v\rangle_T+\langle w,v\rangle_T &&\text{by definition}
\end{align}

Do 2 and 3 similarly.

Only 4 requires $T$ being an isomorphism; suppose $u\ne0$; then, if $v=T(u)$ we have $v\ne0$ because $T$ is an isomorphism and so
$$
\langle u,u\rangle_T=\langle T(u),T(u)\rangle=\langle v,v\rangle>0
$$
by the properties of inner products.

Comment: but where did you use that $<u,v>$ is an inner product?

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs In the third line of the display and also in the second display, where $\langle v,v\rangle>0$ because $\langle \cdot,\cdot\rangle$ is an inner product by assumption.

Comment: I was hoping to write a nice answer using function composition, but this is nice, I don't think I can beat it!